# HTML5 Audio strange behavior with iOS lock screen

Tags: ios, html, audio

I have a website that uses html5 audio blocks to play audio. When I drag the progress bar to jump to another part of the track, the timer stops incrementing and the play/pause button stops working. Does anybody know what properties on an HTML5 audio block the iOS lock screen is reading to show the progress bar?